# What does this thing do?

Tags: mathematics, computer-puzzle

$$(d+(5m+m/9)/2+5y/4-y/C+y/CD+1/(m/3+1)*(2-(1/(y\%4+1)+1/(y\%CD+1)-1/(y\%C+1))))\%7$$

1. What does this thing do? Explain.
2. Can you make it simpler i.e. fewer characters (I will give a nice bounty for this)?

Important information (Hintish):

> This is not a riddlish trick. It is a math formula that would run as Java code.

Comment: I clicked "edit" to copy the TeX for your formula and realised there's a "%7" at the end. For some reason it's invisible in the display form. You need to edit somehow to make it visible!

Answer (score 6):

The only thing I can think of is

> it gives you the day of the week from the date of the year (d,m,y with C and CD giving you information about the century and 4-century for leap-year purposes).

Now I have to work out the algebra to prove it - thanks Cop for wasting my time on this! :-[

---

Edit: looks similar to the C formula

> [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week#Implementation-dependent_methods).

---

### Progress

The input quantities are as follows:

> $d$ is the day, $m$ is the month, $y$ is the year, $C=100$, $CD=400$ (Roman numerals - crafty!).

First consider the quantity $(1/(y\%4+1)+1/(y\%CD+1)-1/(y\%C+1))$. There are four cases to consider:

- if $y$ is not a multiple of 4, then the first fraction is at most $\frac{1}{2}$ and (since 4 divides $CD$ and $C$) the whole sum is less than 1
- if $y$ is a multiple of 4 but not of $C$, then the first fraction is exactly 1 and either the other two are equal or the $C$ one is smaller than the $CD$ one, so the whole sum is at least 1
- if $y$ is a multiple of $C$ but not of $CD$, then the first and last fractions are exactly 1 and cancel out to leave the whole sum less than 1
- if $y$ is a multiple of $CD$, then all three fractions are exactly 1 and the whole sum is 1.

So $(2-(1/(y\%4+1)+1/(y\%CD+1)-1/(y\%C+1)))$ is less than or equal to 1 iff

> the year denoted by $y$ is a leap year.

Also $(m/3+1)$ is less than 2 iff

> the month denoted by $m$ is January or February.

So the final term in the sum, $(1/(m/3+1)(2-(1/(y\%4+1)+1/(y\%CD+1)-1/(y\%C+1))))$, is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$ iff we need to alter the final answer due to

> a leap year.

Comment: well done :) you get a small bounty for part 2

Comment: @d'alar'cop a) What is part 2? b) I don't need any more bounties! :-o

Comment: part 2 is simplifying the formula further... with a proof :p also the progress doesn't fully explain why it works or doesn't

Comment: @d'alar'cop Bleurgh ... don't know if I can be bothered :-p Maybe I'll run it on a load of test cases and say "the evidence suggests it works" or something.

Comment: please also note that the division is "integer division" meaning that the result always rounds down to the nearest integer.

Comment: Why are you talking with yourself?

Comment: @leoll2 ??? Who's talking with themselves?

Comment: C'mon, we both know the truth...  :-)

Comment: @leoll2 Sorry, I don't understand what you're talking about here.

Comment: @randal'thor, I think he's referring to your name having an apostrophe like d'alar'cop's name. On another note, is this not the answer to the puzzle? I'm confused about what's missing to earn that green checkmark.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I actually got the tick but then it was removed again - probably because I haven't fully justified my answer.